# Проблемы с @Autowired в контролле Swing-приложения

Tags: java, mvc, swing, spring, шаблоны-проектирования

Для написания небольшой программки в качестве инструментов выбрал:

1. swing для gui
2. spring
3. hibernate
4. mysql

И еще, чтобы все было более-менее красиво, и на случай, если надо было бы что-то поменять, попытался подогнать все под mvc-шаблон. 
Дабы не морочиться с xml-конфигами, делал бо́льшую часть аннотациями.

Есть некая простая swing форма:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

public MainFrame() {}


public void init() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));


    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
    c.setBounds(20,20,600,400);


    addComponents();

    setVisible(true);
    setState(Frame.NORMAL);
}

private void addComponents() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Adding new hashtag"));
    panel.setBounds(20,20,340,50);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));


    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter hashtag");
    panel.add(label);

    final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(6);
    panel.add(textField);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click to add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

//Следующая строка скорее всего не самый лучший вариант. может кто-то подсажет как написать лучше
                (new HashtagController()).addNewHashTag(textField.getText());
                System.out.println("Added: " + textField.getText());
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        this.add(panel);


    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Component
public class HashtagController {


    @Autowired
    private HashtagDAO hashtagDAO;

    public HashtagController() {
    }

    public Boolean addNewHashTag(String s){
        hashtagDAO.createNewHashtag(new Hashtag(s));
        return null;
    }


}
```

ДАО класс:

```
@Repository
public class HashtagDAOImpl implements HashtagDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HashtagDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HashtagDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void createNewHashtag(Hashtag hashtag) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(hashtag);
        logger.info("Hashtag added succcessfully. Hashtaname: " + hashtag.getTagname());
    }

}
```

spring-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!--<context:annotation-config />-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.smirnov"/>

    <bean id="mainFrame" class="ru.smirnov.gui.MainFrame" init-method="init" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keepinmind"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
          <!-- class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.smirnov.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

При запуске появлется форма с полем, куда можно вписать что-то с клавиатуры, однако  при нажатии кнопки (Добавить) вылетает

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ru.smirnov.controller.HashtagController.addNewHashTag(HashtagController.java:25)`

т.е., HashtagDAO не подхватывается.

Как исправить,? Да и вообще выслушаю ваши комментарии, советы и подобное.

Comment: придерживайтесь, пожалуйста, [принятой практики по поводу приветствий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93/178576). да и заголовок хорошо бы дать более соответствующий возникшей ошибке.

Comment: А почему метод, возвращающий `Boolean`, возвращает `null`? Есть подозрения, что исключение выбрасывается из-за того, что вы не проинициализировали `hashtagDAO`.

Comment: @LEQADA, пока это особой роли-то не играет, т.к. возвращаемое значение пока нигде не используется.

Comment: @LEQADA понятное дело, что непроинициализировано. вопрос как бы это сделать используя spring фичи. Фишка в том что можно конечно через конструктор инициализировать, но тут, как по мне, проблема появится при инициализации самого HashtagController в гуи.

Comment: Если вам не надо много копий HashtagController, то сделайте поле HashtagController hashtagController в MainFrame  и подтяните его @Autowired аннотацией. Потом вызывайте не (new HashtagController()), а hashtagController

Answer (score 2):

В своем примере вы не используете DI, а создаете экземпляр класса вручную.

```
(new HashtagController()).addNewHashTag(textField.getText());
```

Естественно, при таком подходе ничего не работать не будет, потому что DI контейнер ничего не знает и не может знать о вашем экземпляре класса. Чтобы заинжектить DAO нужно инициализировать контекст спринга и запрашивать бины из него:

```
final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
final HashtagDAO dao = (HashtagDAO) context.getBean("myDaoName");
```

А дальше можете передать этот DAO котроллеру через сеттер. Или отдавайте контроллер под управление DI.